# C++ introduction: self study

Tags: c++

I created the program to read from text file and remove special characters. I can't seem to code better the if statement. Please help. I searched online for the right code statements but they have all advanced code statements. The book I am learning from has the last(14th) chapter with strings and file open and closing code. I tried creating an array of special chars, but did not work. Please help me!

```
     int main()
     {


 string paragraph = "";
 string curChar = "";
 string fileName = "";
 int subscript=0;
 int numWords=0;


 ifstream inFile; //declaring the file variables in the implement
 ofstream outFile;


       cout << "Please enter the input file name(C:\owner\Desktop\para.txt): " << endl;

       cin >> fileName;


 inFile.open(fileName, ios::in); //opening the user entered file

 //if statement for not finding the file
 if(inFile.fail())
 {
  cout<<"error opening the file.";
 }
 else
 {
 getline(inFile,paragraph);
 cout<<paragraph<<endl<<endl;
 }


 numWords=paragraph.length();

 while (subscript < numWords)
 {

  curChar = paragraph.substr(subscript, 1);


      if(curChar==","||curChar=="."||curChar==")"
   ||curChar=="("||curChar==";"||curChar==":"||curChar=="-"
   ||curChar=="\""||curChar=="&"||curChar=="?"||
      curChar=="%"||curChar=="$"||curChar=="!"||curChar=="                ["||curChar=="]"||
   curChar=="{"||curChar=="}"||curChar=="_"||curChar=="  <"||curChar==">"
     ||curChar=="/"||curChar=="#"||curChar=="*"||curChar=="_"||curChar=="+"
   ||curChar=="=")


  {
   paragraph.erase(subscript, 1);
   numWords-=1;
  }
  else 
   subscript+=1;

 }

 cout<<paragraph<<endl;
 inFile.close();
```

Comment: It would help if you (a) formatted your code and (b) pasted your entire code.  The braces are not balanced in the code you posted.  You also need to explain "did not work."  What did not work?  Did it not compile?  Did it not run?  Did it run but give the wrong result?  Did it run but give the right result then crash?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific here : what is not working ? Does it fail to compile ? If so, what is the error message ? What is the expected behavior ?

Comment: I don't understand this correctly, you mean you want to read a file, remove certain characters and close it, but the above code doesn't work?

Comment: The way it is now is perfectly working. When I used a string array of special chars and applied in the if statement the program just breaks down and I have to stop debugging.

Comment: I want to change the if statement into a more meaningful and simple.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into the `strchr` function which searches a string for a given character:

```
include <string.h>
char *strchr (const char *s, int c);
```

> The strchr function locates the first occurrence of c (converted to a char) in the
>   string pointed to by s. The terminating null character is considered to be part of the
>   string.
>
> The strchr function returns a pointer to the located character, or a null pointer if the
>   character does not occur in the string.

Something like:

```
if (strchr (",.();:-\"&?%$![]{}_<>/#*_+=", curChar) != NULL) ...
```

You'll have to declare `curChar` as a `char` rather than a `string` and use:

```
curChar = paragraph[subscript];
```

rather than:

```
curChar = paragraph.substr(subscript, 1);
```

but they're relatively minor changes and, since your stated goal was `I want to change the if statement into [something] more meaningful and simple`, I think you'll find that's a very good way to achieve it.

Comment: `strchr`'s the way I'd go too, but not curChar is currently string!  @Luckywhy: you should change it to a `char` and set it to `paragraph[subscript]` instead of `paragraph.substr(subscript, 1)`.

Comment: @Luckwhy: sure you can, pointers work just fine. Unless this is homework (usually the case when there are silly restrictions that have no place in the real world), in which case you should probably tag it such. If you're self-studying, you should learn the best way to do things rather than imposing unnecessary limits.

Comment: @Luckywhy: you don't need to understand pointers for this use strchr... just need to know that it searches through the characters in the string on the left, and if none are found it returns NULL, otherwise something else....

Answer (score 1):

In `<cctype>` header we have functions like `isalnum(c)` which returns true iff c is an alpanumeric character, `isdigit(c)` etc... I think the condition you are looking for is

`if(isgraph(c) && !isalnum(c))`

But c must be a `char`, not an `std::string` (well, technically speaking c must be `int`, but the conversion is implicit:) hth

P.S. This isn't the best idea, but if you want to keep sticking with `std::string` for `curChar`, c will be this `char c = curChar[0]`

Comment: since those statements are not taught in the book I cannot use them.

Comment: @Luckwhy: I beg your pardon? Why can't you use them? This is a perfectly standard header and standard functions inherited from the C language. Do use them :)

Answer (score 0):

since you are learning c++, I will introduce you the c++ iterator way of erasing.

```
for (string::iterator it = paragraph.begin();
        it != paragraph.end();
        ++it)
    while (it != paragraph.end() && (*it == ',' || *it == '.' || ....... ))
        it = paragraph.erase(it);
```

First, try using `iterator`. This won't give you best performance, but its concept would help you work with other c++ structure.

```
if(curChar==","||curChar=="."||curChar==")"  ......
```

Second, single quote `'` and double quote `"` differs. You use `'` for `char`.

Comment: after `paragraph.erase(it);` the iterator is invalidated, and so the subsequent `++it` is undefined.